# testing an EMMC disk in an embedded system

Tags: testing, embedded

My task is to think about the implementation of partial and full tests for the emmc disk in the program. I studied the information on the Internet, but the whole point boils down to something completely different. How can I check the performance and suitability of memory using software tests? What does it even need to be checked?  Or does it not make sense, because the emmc disk has a built-in controller that performs all the necessary actions by itself?

Comment: If you want to check performance and suitability, you have requirements. Write your tests against the requirements. If you don't have requirements, you cannot test.